# Connect Conduktor to Kafka Docker container

Tags: macos, docker, apache-kafka

I have a requirement for a small kafka setup for testing.

I'm new to kafka and I can't find a way to connect to a kafka that I setup in docker container:

I tried to use https://hub.docker.com/r/spotify/kafka/ which is a container that contains zookeeper and kafka, but I don't know what is the ip of the kafka:

```
docker run -p 2181:2181 -p 9092:9092 --env ADVERTISED_HOST=`docker-machine ip \`docker-machine active\`` --env ADVERTISED_PORT=9092 spotify/kafka
```

logs:

```
Digest: sha256:cf8f8f760b48a07fb99df24fab8201ec8b647634751e842b67103a25a388981b
Status: Downloaded newer image for spotify/kafka:latest
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:296: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
2020-07-12 19:45:07,018 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2020-07-12 19:45:07,019 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/kafka.conf" during parsing
2020-07-12 19:45:07,019 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/zookeeper.conf" during parsing
2020-07-12 19:45:07,027 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2020-07-12 19:45:07,027 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2020-07-12 19:45:07,027 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2020-07-12 19:45:08,031 INFO spawned: 'zookeeper' with pid 8
2020-07-12 19:45:08,034 INFO spawned: 'kafka' with pid 9
2020-07-12 19:45:09,081 INFO success: zookeeper entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2020-07-12 19:45:09,082 INFO success: kafka entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

I'm using a kafka-ui to connect to it. I'm trying to use:

```
zookeeper: localhost:2181   <--- working

kafka: localhost:9092 <--- ERROR: "The broker [localhost:9092] is reachable
 but Kafka can't connect. ensure you have access to the *advertised listeners* 
 of the cluster and the proper authorizations."
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using Docker Toolbox?  The same `docker-machine ip` command that's in your `docker run` command will give you the IP address to reach Kafka, or any other container.  If not, then you shouldn't need to run any `docker-machine` commands at all.

Comment: Have a read of this: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spotify container is no longer maintained.

I suggest you follow the Confluent Docker quickstart guides or at least use Docker Compose rather than any all-in-one Kafka+ZooKeeper image

---

I will also point you at the blue help content that says "or Docker?"

> but I don't know what is the ip of the kafka:

Its the same IP as Zookeeper, because you're only using a single host here

---

It appears you're using Linux, so it's not clear why you need Docker Machine